# "Protecting" a SQL backup

Tags: backup, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014

The `mediapassword` option that was available when backing up a SQL Server database was discontinued in SQL Server 2012.

Is there a suggested replacement procedure to follow now? I want to protect a database backup so that it can only be reattached to a SQL instance if one knows a secret (like a password). This secret can be generated at the time of the back or restore.

The only people who should be reattaching the database are the clients who own it, or support staff if they need to examine data within it. Because of this, server or SQL instance specific encryption is not an option. The backup and restore is done programmatically so the complexity of the process is not an issue.

What are the available options? Will I have to implement a secondary operation after the backup (like creating a passworded zip of the backup file, or manually encrypt the backup)?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f33a47f-9d5f-49ad-b3cf-aa239f2aaccc/database-encryption-functionality-retired-in-sql-2012?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that things have improved significantly with SQL Server 2014, in that true encryption of backups is now supported.

I'd recommend taking a look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449489(v=sql.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449489%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) for details of how to encrypt a backup using a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do database encryption http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449489.aspx to ensure it is secure

Thanks
Sunil

Comment: SO guidelines say you should add a summary of linked pages.